# i want to abstract text with lstm

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm working on a web scraping project.I have 100 links and I should scrab the first page of all. so my text length is dynamic. I use nltk to make a summary and at the end, I use the code brought here taken from the link in the post in lstm to abstract them. but in the input function, i have a dimension error because I don't know how to get the max_lenght. please help me with this.after line 73 the lstm begine. actually, I use this article for lstm. here is the link https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/06/comprehensive-guide-text-summarization-using-deep-learning-python/. thanks

```
from googlesearch import search   
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import keys 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import PyPDF2
import re
from attention import AttentionLayer
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
import pandas as pd
import datagp as d 
import numpy as np
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer 
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Embedding, Dense, Concatenate, TimeDistributed
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import warnings
max_text_len=30
max_summary_len=8
# to search 
pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth", 200)
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
def search_google():
    query = input('enter the string: ')
    chrome_path=r'D:\python_files\chromedriver.exe'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)
    links = []
    for j in search(query, tld="com", num=3, stop=3, pause=2): 
        links.append(j) 
    
    first_page=[]
    result={}
    
    for l in links:
        if re.search(".pdf",l)==None:
            try:
                driver.get(l)
                elm=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('p')
                first_page=''.join ([i.text for i in elm])
                
                if first_page!='':
                    sum,join_sent,sen_list=d.summary(first_page)
                    w_cloud=d.wordcloud_plot(d.frequency_dist(sen_list))
                    
                    case={'Summary':sum,'Text':join_sent}
                    result[l]=case
                    
                    
            except :
                continue
    
    
    
    
    
    
    r_list=list(result.values())   
    df=pd.DataFrame(result)
    df=df.transpose()
    short_text=''.join([x['Text'] for x in r_list]) 
    short_summary=''.join([x['Summary'] for x in r_list])
    df.to_csv('d:\\result.csv')
    return short_text,short_summary,df

short_text,short_summary,data=search_google()

cleaned_text = []
for t in data['Text']:
    cleaned_text.append(t)

cleaned_summary = []
for t in data['Summary']:
    cleaned_summary.append(t)
    

data.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
data.dropna(axis=0,inplace=True)
data['cleaned_text']=cleaned_text
data['cleaned_summary']=cleaned_summary

cleaned_text =np.array(data['cleaned_text'])
cleaned_summary=np.array(data['cleaned_summary'])

short_text=[]
short_summary=[]

for i in range(len(cleaned_text)):
    short_text.append(cleaned_text[i])
    short_summary.append(cleaned_summary[i])
    
    
cnt=0
for i in data['cleaned_summary']:
    if(len(i.split())<=8):
        cnt=cnt+1
print(cnt/len(data['cleaned_summary']))

df=pd.DataFrame({'text':short_text,'summary':short_summary})


df['summary'] = df['summary'].apply(lambda x : 'sostok '+ x + ' eostok')


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_tr,x_val,y_tr,y_val=train_test_split(np.array(df['text']),np.array(df['summary']),test_size=0.1,random_state=0,shuffle=True)

from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer 
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

#prepare a tokenizer for reviews on training data
x_tokenizer = Tokenizer() 
x_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(list(x_tr))


thresh=4

cnt=0
tot_cnt=0
freq=0
tot_freq=0

for key,value in x_tokenizer.word_counts.items():
    tot_cnt=tot_cnt+1
    tot_freq=tot_freq+value
    if(value<thresh):
        cnt=cnt+1
        freq=freq+value

#prepare a tokenizer for reviews on training data
x_tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=tot_cnt-cnt) 
x_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(list(x_tr))

#convert text sequences into integer sequences
x_tr_seq    =   x_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_tr) 
x_val_seq   =   x_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_val)

#padding zero upto maximum length
x_tr    =   pad_sequences(x_tr_seq,  maxlen=max_text_len, padding='post')
x_val   =   pad_sequences(x_val_seq, maxlen=max_text_len, padding='post')

#size of vocabulary ( +1 for padding token)
x_voc   =  x_tokenizer.num_words + 1

#prepare a tokenizer for reviews on training data
y_tokenizer = Tokenizer()   
y_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(list(y_tr))

thresh=6

cnt=0
tot_cnt=0
freq=0
tot_freq=0

for key,value in y_tokenizer.word_counts.items():
    tot_cnt=tot_cnt+1
    tot_freq=tot_freq+value
    if(value<thresh):
        cnt=cnt+1
        freq=freq+value

#prepare a tokenizer for reviews on training data
y_tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=tot_cnt-cnt) 
y_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(list(y_tr))

#convert text sequences into integer sequences
y_tr_seq    =   y_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(y_tr) 
y_val_seq   =   y_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(y_val) 

#padding zero upto maximum length
y_tr    =   pad_sequences(y_tr_seq, maxlen=max_summary_len, padding='post')
y_val   =   pad_sequences(y_val_seq, maxlen=max_summary_len, padding='post')

#size of vocabulary
y_voc  =   y_tokenizer.num_words +1

y_tokenizer.word_counts['sostok'],len(y_tr)

ind=[]
for i in range(len(y_tr)):
    cnt=0
    for j in y_tr[i]:
        if j!=0:
            cnt=cnt+1
    if(cnt==2):
        ind.append(i)

y_tr=np.delete(y_tr,ind, axis=0)
x_tr=np.delete(x_tr,ind, axis=0)

ind=[]
for i in range(len(y_val)):
    cnt=0
    for j in y_val[i]:
        if j!=0:
            cnt=cnt+1
    if(cnt==2):
        ind.append(i)

y_val=np.delete(y_val,ind, axis=0)
x_val=np.delete(x_val,ind, axis=0)

from keras import backend as K 
K.clear_session()

latent_dim = 300
embedding_dim=100

# Encoder
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(max_text_len,))

#embedding layer
enc_emb =  Embedding(x_voc, embedding_dim,trainable=True)(encoder_inputs)

#encoder lstm 1
encoder_lstm1 = LSTM(latent_dim,return_sequences=True,return_state=True,dropout=0.4,recurrent_dropout=0.4)
encoder_output1, state_h1, state_c1 = encoder_lstm1(enc_emb)

#encoder lstm 2
encoder_lstm2 = LSTM(latent_dim,return_sequences=True,return_state=True,dropout=0.4,recurrent_dropout=0.4)
encoder_output2, state_h2, state_c2 = encoder_lstm2(encoder_output1)

#encoder lstm 3
encoder_lstm3=LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True, return_sequences=True,dropout=0.4,recurrent_dropout=0.4)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c= encoder_lstm3(encoder_output2)

# Set up the decoder, using `encoder_states` as initial state.
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,))

#embedding layer
dec_emb_layer = Embedding(y_voc, embedding_dim,trainable=True)
dec_emb = dec_emb_layer(decoder_inputs)

decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True,dropout=0.4,recurrent_dropout=0.2)
decoder_outputs,decoder_fwd_state, decoder_back_state = decoder_lstm(dec_emb,initial_state=[state_h, state_c])

# Attention layer
attn_layer = AttentionLayer(name='attention_layer')
attn_out, attn_states = attn_layer([encoder_outputs, decoder_outputs])

# Concat attention input and decoder LSTM output
decoder_concat_input = Concatenate(axis=-1, name='concat_layer')([decoder_outputs, attn_out])

#dense layer
decoder_dense =  TimeDistributed(Dense(y_voc, activation='softmax'))
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_concat_input)

# Define the model 
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1,patience=2)


history=model.fit([x_tr,y_tr[:,:-1]], y_tr.reshape(y_tr.shape[0],y_tr.shape[1], 1)[:,1:] ,epochs=50,callbacks=[es],batch_size=128, validation_data=([x_val,y_val[:,:-1]], y_val.reshape(y_val.shape[0],y_val.shape[1], 1)[:,1:]))

reverse_target_word_index=y_tokenizer.index_word
reverse_source_word_index=x_tokenizer.index_word
target_word_index=y_tokenizer.word_index


# Encode the input sequence to get the feature vector
encoder_model = Model(inputs=encoder_inputs,outputs=[encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c])

# Decoder setup
# Below tensors will hold the states of the previous time step
decoder_state_input_h = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_state_input_c = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_hidden_state_input = Input(shape=(max_text_len,latent_dim))

# Get the embeddings of the decoder sequence
dec_emb2= dec_emb_layer(decoder_inputs) 
# To predict the next word in the sequence, set the initial states to the states from the previous time step
decoder_outputs2, state_h2, state_c2 = decoder_lstm(dec_emb2, initial_state=[decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c])

#attention inference
attn_out_inf, attn_states_inf = attn_layer([decoder_hidden_state_input, decoder_outputs2])
decoder_inf_concat = Concatenate(axis=-1, name='concat')([decoder_outputs2, attn_out_inf])

# A dense softmax layer to generate prob dist. over the target vocabulary
decoder_outputs2 = decoder_dense(decoder_inf_concat) 

# Final decoder model
decoder_model = Model(
    [decoder_inputs] + [decoder_hidden_state_input,decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c],
    [decoder_outputs2] + [state_h2, state_c2])


def decode_sequence(input_seq):
    # Encode the input as state vectors.
    e_out, e_h, e_c = encoder_model.predict(input_seq)
    
    # Generate empty target sequence of length 1.
    target_seq = np.zeros((1,1))
    
    # Populate the first word of target sequence with the start word.
    target_seq[0, 0] = target_word_index['sostok']

    stop_condition = False
    decoded_sentence = ''
    while not stop_condition:
      
        output_tokens, h, c = decoder_model.predict([target_seq] + [e_out, e_h, e_c])

        # Sample a token
        sampled_token_index = np.argmax(output_tokens[0, -1, :])
        sampled_token = reverse_target_word_index[sampled_token_index]
        
        if(sampled_token!='eostok'):
            decoded_sentence += ' '+sampled_token

        # Exit condition: either hit max length or find stop word.
        if (sampled_token == 'eostok'  or len(decoded_sentence.split()) >= (max_summary_len-1)):
            stop_condition = True

        # Update the target sequence (of length 1).
        target_seq = np.zeros((1,1))
        target_seq[0, 0] = sampled_token_index

        # Update internal states
        e_h, e_c = h, c

    return decoded_sentence

def seq2summary(input_seq):
    newString=''
    for i in input_seq:
        if((i!=0 and i!=target_word_index['sostok']) and i!=target_word_index['eostok']):
            newString=newString+reverse_target_word_index[i]+' '
    return newString

def seq2text(input_seq):
    newString=''
    for i in input_seq:
        if(i!=0):
            newString=newString+reverse_source_word_index[i]+' '
    return newString

for i in range(0,3):
    print("Review:",seq2text(x_tr[i]))
    print("Original summary:",seq2summary(y_tr[i]))
    print("Predicted summary:",decode_sequence(x_tr[i].reshape(1,max_text_len)))
    print("\n")
```

Comment: Can you add the exact stack trace? You have mentioned error after line 73. That is at line `short_text,short_summary,data=search_google()` - is this correct?

Comment: yes  this correct

Answer (score 0):

Tokenize short_summary: Each short_summary tokenize and find the longest list, that will give you max_length.
Sample code snippet

```
vocabulary = []
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
tokenizer = tfds.features.text.Tokenizer()
for text_tokens in short_summary:
     some_tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text_token.numpy())
     vocabulary.update(some_tokens)

Find the longest sentence,
import numpy as np
def find_max_list_idx(list):
    list_len = [len(i) for i in list]
    return np.argmax(np.array(list_len))
```